# Rails 6.1.3 lazy loading images

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-6, ruby-on-rails-6.1

I try to use this:

```
config.action_view.image_loading = "lazy"
```

for my app in Rails 6.1.3. According to article it should work ... but it doesn't. I only see 500 errors like

```
 http://localhost:3000/stylesheets/application.css net::ERR_ABORTED 500 (Internal 
 Server Error)

 GET http://localhost:3000/images/logotype.png 500 (Internal Server Error)
```

and there is no graphics on site or images.

Does someone know how to use it ? or maybe it's not implemented yet in Rails?